# How to make senior manager aware of their own inappropriate behaviour if they have no sense of their external effect?

Tags: communication, germany

A senior manager in my company, who I don't report to but occasionally work with, sometimes makes inappropriate comments in small talk without realising it himself. We have an almost buddy-like relationship, but the hierarchical levels that separate us prevent me from addressing the issue frankly. Although the bluntness left me speechless sometimes, I can laugh about the comments afterwards. But another colleague might take it differently and get him into trouble under labour law.

An example of one of his statements to me was shortly after my return from parental leave, when he asked whether we are planning another child and if we are already "in the process" (with a weird look). This was followed by the comment that he had had his children in quick succession at the time.
Another example was when I changed my hairstyle and he commented in a meeting with some foremans if my wife likes it "wild".

How can you make him aware of this behaviour and point out the danger of such ill-considered statements without coming across as rude or threatening as he seems to not realize how inappropriate the comments are? I'm sure it's not meant to be offensive and that he really isn't aware of his external effect.

Comment: Weird question to me. How to make him aware? Tell him when it happens. "I don't think that's appropriate to discuss/comment on in the work place". If that is already too "on the nose" to tell that boss, the question is something else entirely that seems to be about making them realise their errors themselves rather than just making them aware of it. I feel like this borders on an interpersonal question rather than workplace, because you have many options that are professionally viable (that i'm sure you're aware of already), but maybe not quite tactful enough on a personal level.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. As a non-native speaker, can you tell me the difference between "make them aware" and "make them realise"?

Comment: The difference there is whether *you* are going to make them realise these mistakes directly, or want to nudge them to realise their mistakes *themselves*. It doesn't need to be rude that you're telling them something is really inappropriate, and surely it's not more rude than them commenting on your sex-life unprompted. And if this carries too much of a risk of sounding rude or threatening (which it really shouldn't), then we're more or less asking how to make someone see the error in their own ways, which isn't really workplace related. Workplace solutions would be HR, higher ups etc.

Comment: No offence, but it seems more like a "you're right boss" kind of relationship to me than a "buddy-like", if you can't even speak your mind on such inappropriate things.

Answer (score 5):

The remarks are not obviously inappropriate as stated in writing, especially if you feel you are on very good terms with this manager.

We all say all sorts of things to our friends which would be potentially intolerable if said to strangers, and being colleagues is not incompatible with being friends.

If there isn't more to suggest this manager is going to fall out with somebody else, or that he makes these remarks regardless of the relationship with the listener, then I would take them as well-judged friendly banter between friends.

Comment: "he commented in a meeting with some foremans if my wife likes it "wild"." That doesn't sound like well-judged friendly banter to me

Comment: It's probably fine if it's in the context of hair.

Comment: @mattfreake, the speaker was referring to the OPs hairstyle, when he asked whether his wife "likes it wild"!

Comment: @Steve Fair enough, my mind is in the gutter so I just read a double meaning there.

Comment: @Steve: My interpretation of "likes it wild" was that it was referring to the wife enjoying having wild sex, and the manager therefore implying that OP's hairstyle was a result of having had wild sex with their wife. This thematically ties into the other example (asking if they're working on the second baby) in that it references the OP's sexual activities, which is inappropriate. I don't speak German but I do speak a very closely related sibling language (Dutch) and "liking it [adjective]" is very commonly used to refer to sexual preference.

Comment: @Flater, ah I see the logic: proposing that the cause of a dishevelled hairstyle may have been wild sex. Still, crucially, the question is about hair, not the wife's sexual preferences. And I still think this ultimately comes down to the relationships involved. Such a reference is undoubtedly beyond what is acceptable by default between all workplace contacts, but in my experience, well within how two familiar colleagues (especially two men) may choose to talk.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you have "an almost buddy-like relationship". But then you say "hierarchical levels that separate us prevent me from addressing the issue frankly" and you also say then when he asks you a personal question you find it inappropriate - asking about your family plans is something buddies do, even work colleagues. Those two things mean you don't have a "buddy" relationship - he is a senior manager and you are his employee.

If you are OK with the things he says to you then I would not worry about it. It's his problem if he says something inappropriate to another person. You haven't given any examples when he does that, so maybe he also thinks you are his "buddy" and can say things to you that he can't say to other people.

If you are not OK with that then in an ideal world you should start by talking to him; you tell him how you feel about the things that he says and ask him to stop. That's going to be problematic and you've already said you don't feel you can do it - but it's what "buddies" do. If you've set up the sort of relationship where he thinks he is your "buddy" then you kind of owe him to treat him like one.

If you can't do that the next place to go is to your boss. Ask for advice on how to deal with this issue. Don't make it a "complaint" unless that's what you want - your boss may be able to pass the message gently up the chain of command until it reaches someone who is in a position to say something to him. Be aware that this will hurt any relationship you think you have - buddies don't get other people to tell them about their behaviour.

If none of that works and you still want this to stop go to HR. However be aware that there will be repercussions if you do this - you will almost certainly lose whatever special relationship you have with this person. You may find you aren't getting preferential treatment, or even getting unpreferential treatment. Only make your compalint formal if you are prepared for the consequences.

Comment: Upvoted. I agree with everything in this answer, except the jump from "you've already said you don't feel you can do it" to "the next place to go is to your boss". It shouldn't be that hard to say "sorry, I know you meant that as a friendly joke, but I'd really prefer we don't discuss my sex life" to the senior manager the next time they make an inappropriate joke. Direct and honest communication will go a long way to deescalate the situation peacefully, especially as opposed to pretending the joke is okay but then escalating the situation up the hierarchy behind the senior manager's back.